# copy values in a python list to a dictionary

Tags: python

If I have a list,

```
lstValues=[1, 2, "cat", "meow"]
```

And I have a dictionary with keys as follows:

```
data {id, count, animal, sound}
```

If I am reading from a file formatted as follows:

```
#id count animal sound
10 1 tiger purr
11 2 lion roar
```

I am reading the file and each line is split to return the list of the above format, is there a way to append values from list to dictionary?

So if what I am asking were to be possible, I would be able to do something like:

```
data.append(lstValues)
```

I know dictionary keys have no set order. I am fairly sure this is not possible but I would like a confirmation.

**EDIT:** I want to avoid doing a manual assignment. I know dicts dont support the syntax I provided as an example, which is why I said "something like".

Comment: cant ya just do `s = line.split()` and then individually assign them as `data['id'] = s[0]`, `data['count'] = s[1]` , `data['animal'] = s[2]` ... etc? Brute force is d best always. (No tension)

Comment: Do you want to have a single dictionary containing all the animals, or one dictionary for each animal?

Comment: I'm afraid your make a confusion between a Python dictionary which is a hash with keys and values, and a database table which has *columns* (here `id`, `count`, `animal and `sound`) and *rows* (here  `10`, `1`, `tiger`, `purr` , etc.). Please clearly explain what you are trying to achieve, it is currently *unclear* and your question could be closed for that reason.

Comment: @BhargavRao that is what I was trying to avoid. Yes, I can certainly do it, but I want to know if there is a more elegant or better way to do it.

Comment: @powerrox Your edit makes your question look good. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way:

```
keys = ["id", "count", "animal", "sound"]

lstValues = [1, 2, "cat", "meow"]

data = dict(zip(keys, lstValues))
```

The `zip` function combines the two lists into a list of tuples (each tuple is a key and a value). The `dict` function converts the list of tuples into a dictionary.

Comment: Shouldn't you use izip from itertools (generators).  The OP may be zipping lots of data.

Comment: excellent solution. just what i was looking for.  @msanti, I am zipping one row at a time, so zip maybe sufficient. But +1 for a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

if data is a dict then you can not use append. 
try this -

```
data = {}
data['id'] = lstValues[0]
data['count'] = lstValues[1]
data['animal'] = lstValues[2]
data['sound'] = lstValues[02]
print data
```